# No mostrar el texto de un TextBox

Tags: c#

en un TextBox de un WindowsForms por defecto desde su propiedad Text ya tiene un valor, es decir ya contiene un texto. Lo que necesito es que este texto no sea visible para el usuario, puse en la propiedad del TextBox los mismos colores en el ForeColor y en el BackColor, logicamente no es visible el texto pero cuando se selecciona con el mouse el TextBox resalta y lo hace visible, una solucion es poner la propiedad visible del TextBox a false pero quiero lograrlo sin tener que ocultar el TextBox.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Si estás usando WinForms, podrías usar el método [Clear](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.clear?view=netframework-4.8) para borrar el contenido del textBox y el evento [TextChanged](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged?view=netframework-4.8) lo usarías para llamar al método [Clear](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.clear?view=netframework-4.8).

El problema radica, que necesitas tener guardado en una variable auxiliar el texto introducido por el usuario, eso se soluciona fácilamente, asignando el contenido de la propiedad Text a la variable auxiliar antes de eliminar el texto con [Clear](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.clear?view=netframework-4.8).

Por ejemplo:

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string txtAux = "";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Guardamos el texto actual en la variable auxiliar
            txtAux  += textBox1.Text;
            //Borramos el contenido actual del TextBox
            textBox1.Clear();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Imprimimos el texto introducido por el usuario
            MessageBox.Show(txtAux);
        }
    }
}
```